# Navigation Drawer Backstacks with Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, back-stack, onbackpressed

My app uses a navigation drawer with 2 sections.

Section 1: Character List, Favorites List

Section 2: List of all characters

Character List has the same character selections as section 2 in the navigation drawer. Selecting a character from "Character List" or "Favorites List" in section 1, or from the list in the drawer, will open the character page.

When I am on a character page, I want the back button to bring the user back to the Character List or Favorites List (whichever was last accessed), but never back to a previous Character Page (if it was selected from the navigation drawer).

My Drawer item listener:

```
public void getDrawerItemClickListener() {
        mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                int selection = menuItem.getItemId();
                String name = menuItem.getTitle().toString();


                if(selection == R.id.nav_home) {
                    Fragment myFragment = new HomeFragment();
                    replaceFragment(myFragment);
                }

                if(selection == R.id.nav_fav) {
                    Fragment myFragment = new FavFragment();
                    replaceFragment(myFragment);
                }


                for(int i = 0; i < characters.size(); i++) {
                    if(characters.get(i).getName().equals(name))
                    {
                        Fragment myFragment = new TabFragment();
                        myFragment.setArguments(createCharacterBundle(characters.get(i)));
                        replaceFragment(myFragment);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }

        });
    }
```

My replaceFragment method:

```
 public void replaceFragment(Fragment myFragment) {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.containerView, myFragment);
            transaction.commit();
    }
```

And my onBackPressed method:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                mDrawerOpen = true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                mDrawerOpen = false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {

            }
        });



public void onBackPressed() {
   if (mDrawerOpen) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(DrawableItemResourceID);
        return;
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```